# USB device connected which host

Tags: usb

How do my device(may be phone) know to which host connected like windows OS or mac OS or linux OS? Do we have any kernel command or utility from device side which knows/extracts host information?

Answer (score 1):

It can't tell unless,

- the host cooperates in the detection process by sending information to the device, there is no standard for this in USB, or
- the device fingerprints the host based on its behavior. For example, Windows enumerates USB devices with a slightly different sequence of requests than OS X. Linux tries to mimic the Windows behavior because devices are buggy.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. But my requirement is simple to know the host side OS. is it Windows or MAC or Linux? So, do we have any workaround solution or hooks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea: http://cise.ufl.edu/~butler/pubs/sadfe11.pdf

It's about reading the suspended and reset time, and mapping a USB fingerprint.